# jericho Html parser error in jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, html-parsing

I have write code as

```
String sourceUrlString="http://some url";
Source source=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
Element INFORM = source.getElementById("main").getAllElementsByClass("game").get(i-1);
String INFORM = INFORM.replaceAll("\\s","");   //shows error here
sendResponse(resp,+INFORM);
```

Now i want the *text* fetch from Element `INFORM` is Neglect white space how can i do so? above mentioned `String INFORM` Show error *Duplicate local variable INFORM*);

e.g

text fetch by Element INFORM is "my name is satish"
but it must send response as

"mynameissatish"

Answer (score 0):

You have the name `INFORM` used twice - and thats not possible!

```
String sourceUrlString = "http://some url";
Source source = new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
Element INFORM = source.getElementById("main").getAllElementsByClass("game").get(i-1);
String response = INFORM.replaceAll("\\s","");   // ! Use another name here !
sendResponse(resp, respone); // or use '+' - not shure if 1 or 2 args
```